# Number of samples in each epoch for CNN Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a problem with understanding the number of observations in each epoch step.

I implemented CNN in Keras to recognize checkered pattern in the picture, and. I prepared 240 images for training and 60 images for cross validation, with data augmentation.

```py
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical')
```

Next I trained my CNN:

```py
history = model.fit_generator(
                train_generator,
                steps_per_epoch = 240,
                epochs=epochs,
                validation_data=validation_generator,
                validation_steps= 60)
```

And I got the output

```py
Found 240 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 60 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/50
7/7[==============================] - 45s - loss: 4.1905 - acc: 0.4777 - val_loss: 0.7081 - val_acc: 0.5000  
Epoch 2/50
7/7[==============================] - 41s - loss: 0.7049 - acc: 0.0.4973 - val_loss: 0.6851 - val_acc: 0.6786
```

And my question is why 7? If I correctly understand it should be 240. This is 7 because of the bath size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your batch_size is 32. It means that is uses 32 images per step.
For 1 epoch it needs to parse 240. 
240/32 = 7.5
you need to change steps_per_epoch from 240 to 8 (`np.ceil(7.5)`)
and `validation_steps` from 60 to 2

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand.
I have one more question, how this image data generator works? For each call (for each epoch) it generates this random changes in the pictures?

Comment: That's right. For each epoch ImageDataGenerator, randomly generates changes in the pictures.

Comment: Ok. Thanks you very much for your help!